# How to filter Decimal Numbers and parentheses () Pyspark / multiple conditions

Tags: pyspark

I would like to filter decimal numbers and parentheses.
Could you Help me?

| A header | content | date | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2.1234 | 2023-10-13 | Wrong |
| SAP1 | 0.1 | 2023-10-11 | Wrong |
| 5673 | 1(341) | 2023-04-06 | Wrong |
| SAAA | 123 | 2023-05-07 | Correct |
| BAAA | 234 | Null | Wrong |

How can I detect decimal numbers and parentheses and null dates and create the result column based on the content and date table?

I want to create the result table or filtering out only those that are wrong

Comment: looks like the `content` field is of string type. if so, you can search for `"."` and `"("` in the values with [`instr`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.instr.html#pyspark-sql-functions-instr)